# sumar celdas de Jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Buen día, tengo un pequeño problema, tengo 2 tablas en un mismo panel, una me carga facturas pendientes, al hacer click sobre ellas se agregan a la seguanda Jtable, hasta ahí todo anda perfecto, ahora tengo un Jlabel que necesito que me muestre el importe que se va agregando en la segunda tabla, es decir a medida que voy haciendo click en la primera tabla los datos del importe de las facturas que van pasando a la segunda tabla se sumen en ese Jlabel. probe algunos codigos y me da 0 todo el tiempo. Alguna ayuda? Algo importante es que la columna importe tiene un numberformat.Muchas Gracias colegas! [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de una imagen deberías por tu código, es imposible detectar o solucionar errores sin él https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Seguimos con el mismo ejemplo de la otra respuesta. Espero que te sirva.

```
private float sumarImporte(){
        DefaultTableModel dtm;
        //LA VARIABLE QUE ALMACENARA EL TOTAL.
        float importeTotal = 0;
        //RECORREMOS TODAS LAS FILAS PERO EN ESTA OCASION SUMAMOS SOLO
        // LA QUE TIENE EL IMPORTE. 
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla2.getRowCount(); i++) {
            //LLAMAMOS EL MODELO DE LA TABLA.
            dtm = (DefaultTableModel)tabla2.getModel();
             //HACEMOS LA CONVERSION CON UN PARSE PARA QUE NO DE ERROR. 
            // EN ESTA PARTE HAY QUE TENER CUIDADO DE QUE LA CELDA 
            // NO CONTENGA LITERALES PUES NOS MANDARA ERROR. 

            //ESTA ES LA NUEVA LINEA.
            String a = tabla2.getValueAt(i, 2)+"";
            a = a.replace(".", "");
            a = a.replace(",", ".");


            float importe = Float.parseFloat(a);
            //SUMAMOS LA FILA ACTUAL AL TOTAL GLOBAL.  
            importeTotal+=importe;
        }
        //RETORNAMOS EL RESULTADO DE LA SUMA. 
        return importeTotal;
    }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Cambiar el formato que obtienes de la tabla con estas líneas:

```
            String a = tabla2.getValueAt(i, 2)+"";
            a = a.replace(".", "");
            a = a.replace(",", ".");
```

Comment: lo probe, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, esta vez me dio un error


Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.289,57"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea Prueba cambiando el formato de números que tienes en tu tabla antes de realizar la suma. Lo que pasa es que está interpretando la coma como si fuera texto.

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea Intenta con el decimalFormat para revertir el numberFormat que haces.

Comment: como seria eso? u.u

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea ya actualize la pregunta. No use el decimalFormat. Espero te sirva.

Comment: perfecto! ahora como hago para que se muestre en mi Jlabel?

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea Esta funcion la ejecutas dentro del evento que cambias las filas a la segúnda tabla, despues del movimiento. Ahora dentro la función agrega `this.elNombreDeLaEtiqueta.setText(totalDeLaOperacion)`

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería la idea básica de lo que quieres hacer:

```
Double valores=new Double(0.0);
for (int i = 0; i < tabla2.getRowCount(); i++) {
    Double valor = new Double( tabla2.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
    valores += valor;
}
etiqueta.setText(valores.toString());
```

Comment: lo probe y me da un error...
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.289,57"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)